# Get Array of Enum values less specified item

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I have an enum as follows:

```
private enum Actions {
    f, 
    c,  
    r, 
    a 
}
```

I can get all of the enum values in an array like so:

```
Actions[] all = Actions.values();
```

I would like to be able to get the array of values less a specified value, e.g. excluding f. I think something like this should do what I need but I can't get the usage right:

```
Actions[] noF = Arrays.stream( Actions.values() )
        .filter( value -> value != Actions.f )
        .toArray();
```

I'd like a one line solution like the method I'm trying if possible. Can anybody assist?

Comment: You need to use `toArray(Actions[]::new)` to get the correct type of array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this

```
Actions[] noF = Arrays.stream( Actions.values() )
        .filter( value -> value != Actions.f )
        .toArray(Actions[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) for doing the work:

```
Set<Actions> exceptF = EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(Actions.f));

// Object array
Object[] exceptFObjectArray = exceptF.toArray();

// or Actions array
Actions[] exceptFActionsArray = exceptF.toArray(new Actions[0]);
```

Or in one go:

```
Actions[] exceptF = EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(Actions.f))
        .toArray(new Actions[0]);
```

I think this is a lot more readable than using a stream like you do.

Comment: This is great too Mark. Its close which should be correct answer. Sorry but I went with Debmalya

Comment: @SteveW No problem, I just wanted to provide an alternative: just because you can do things with stream, doesn't mean you need to (or should) use them ;)